# Scala Receiving List[String] from Controller

Tags: mongodb, scala

I am new to Scala and MongDB and I'd like to get Records from a collection which matches a particular ID (In C# or java it is quite an easy thing to do). But in Mongo+Scala I cannot get it to work. My function is:

```
getBooksFlow(bookId: String, booknodes:List[String]): Future[List[bookResponseModel]] 
= {
    val mainDB = connection.db(bookId)
    val bookscollection = mainDB.collection[JSONCollection](booksCollectionString)     
    val query = Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$in"->Json.toJson(booknodes)))  
    var futurebooks = bookscollection.find(query).cursor[bookResponseModel]().collect[List]()
}
```

This is how the query looks when printed:

```
{"_id":{"$in":["0a416b7d-c3a8-329b-93b9-a7296e2d58d9,817e8aa6-7c60-36a3-9213-9bfcf954e541"]}}
```

But I'd like it to be like this:

```
{"_id":{"$in":["0a416b7d-c3a8-329b-93b9-a7296e2d58d9","817e8aa6-7c60-36a3-9213-9bfcf954e541"]}}
```

Anyone knows how to get this right?

Answer (score 0):

It appears your `booknodes:List[String]` is a list of string containing just one item:

```
List("0a416b7d-c3a8-329b-93b9-a7296e2d58d9,817e8aa6-7c60-36a3-9213-9bfcf954e541")
```

Perhaps, split `booknodes` at the commas to get a list of these object IDs. So, your query could look like this:

```
Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$in"->Json.toJson(booknodes.flatMap(_.split(",")))))
```

Comment: Robert Udah its working Fine But if  my data contains (,) which fails the situation  what my question was why controller receving the data  like that List("0a416b7d-c3a8-329b-93b9-a7296e2d58d9,817e8aa6-7c60-36a3-9213-9bfcf954e541")

Comment: Whatever calls `getBooksFlow()` will give you a clue on why your `booknodes` List has a string with commas. Do you mind posting the bit of code where the value of `booknodes` is assigned?

Comment: Robert Udah   window.location = "/getBooksFlow?bookId=@bookInfo.Id& booknodes ="+books   iam calling the control method from the ui page directly ( i thought it is the mistake)  alternative  passing through form but i called  using window.location

Comment: I'm not sure how the URL values get translated. If you are using Play!, include the router value for that URL